# Select all matching rows but only display latest

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a query which displays all matching reports for the last day of the month (i.e. full month reports)

```
SELECT  id, 
    DATE_FORMAT( start_date,  '%e-%b-%y' ) AS start_date, 
    DATE_FORMAT( end_date,  '%e-%b-%y' ) AS end_date, 
    DATE_FORMAT( end_date,  '%M %Y' ) as report_month
FROM Reports
WHERE customer_id ='2321'
  AND end_of_month_file = '1'
```

Problem is duplicates - some files have been processed more than once...

```
id start_date  end_date   report_month
1  1-Feb-14    28-Feb-14  February 2014
2  1-Mar-14    31-Mar-14  March 2014
3  1-Mar-14    31-Mar-14  March 2014
4  1-Mar-14    31-Mar-14  March 2014
5  1-Mar-14    31-Mar-14  March 2014
6  1-Mar-14    31-Mar-14  March 2014
7  1-Mar-14    31-Mar-14  March 2014
8  1-Mar-14    31-Mar-14  March 2014
9  1-Mar-14    31-Mar-14  March 2014
```

how can I filter the results to just give me the last one/latest entry for each month?

Comment: Show your sample dataset

Comment: Consider providing proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) TOGETHER WITH THE DESIRED RESULT SET

Comment: Define "latest entry" please.  Recognize that the value of `id` should be considered random - depending on how transactions are structured in your application, anything with an updateable `createdDate` timestamp may invalidate ordering based on `id`.

Answer (score 1):

Use `GROUP BY` and then sort latest:

```
SELECT  id, 
    DATE_FORMAT( start_date,  '%e-%b-%y' ) AS start_date, 
    DATE_FORMAT( end_date,  '%e-%b-%y' ) AS end_date, 
    DATE_FORMAT( end_date,  '%M %Y' ) as report_month
FROM Reports
WHERE customer_id ='2321'
  AND end_of_month_file = '1'
GROUP BY start_date
ORDER BY start_date DESC;
```

Comment: This dataset only shows one month but down the track, there could be many months with many duplciates

Comment: @php-b-grader If you're saying there's still duplicates after that, you can always group by the other fields too: `GROUP BY start_date,end_date,report_month`

Comment: yes, while this partially works, it gives the first id (not the latest/last id) - this might be ok however, it is likely that the last report is going to be the most up to date - is it possible to get the last date?

Comment: @php-b-grader try changing `DESC` to `ASC`. Or, you can try to change the column that you are ordering by.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have MySQL why not use LIMIT:

```
SELECT  id, 
    DATE_FORMAT( start_date,  '%e-%b-%y' ) AS start_date, 
    DATE_FORMAT( end_date,  '%e-%b-%y' ) AS end_date, 
    DATE_FORMAT( end_date,  '%M %Y' ) as report_month
FROM Reports
WHERE customer_id ='2321'
  AND end_of_month_file = '1'
ORDER BY start_date DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: If I have an end of month report for every month in the last 12 months, this will only give me the last month

Comment: I read the OP to mean that is what you wanted: "how can I filter the results to just give me the last one". Maybe you should post your desired output? It could be that fabricating a column with the MONTH and YEAR, and then using DISTINCT instead of LIMIT is what you want here.